# Create Ruby Gem from Rails classes to use in Sinatra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sinatra

I'm trying to extract several classes from a Rails app into its own Gem so that I can reuse the code from a Sinatra app.

In the Rails app I have the following structure:

```
app > classes > api > (bunch of folders and subfiles)
```

I'm trying to move the `api` folder into a gem, for that I created a new gem using bundler:

```
bundle gem myapp-core --no-exe --no-coc --no-mit --no-ext
```

so I ended up with a file structure like:

```
myapp-core > lib > myapp > core > version.rb
myapp-core > lib > myapp > core.rb
```

I've copied the `api` folder to `myapp-core > lib > myapp > api` and tried to `require` it from sinatra doing:

```
require 'myapp/api/somefile.rb'
```

but that didn't work, I have of course added the gem to the Gemfile of the sinatra app.
I tried all kinds of combinations of where to put the folder and how to require the files in it but I either get  `cannot load such file` or `uninitialized constant Api (NameError)`.

What is the correct way to go about this so that ideally from both Sinatra and Rails I would just add the gem to the Gemfile, require whatever file I need and the code that uses those API files would remain unchanged or change as little as possible?

Comment: Tip: `require` should not have `.rb` in the path. It's assumed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the Rails auto-loader you'll need to establish all the intermediate class and module components yourself.

This usually means you need to either declare things like:

```rb
module Api
  class Somefile
    # ...
  end
end
```

Where that `Api` module is automatically declared, allowing you to require `lib/api/somefile` directly, or you need to shift this responsibility up the chain:

```rb
# lib/api.rb
module Api
  # ...
end

require_relative './api/somefile'
```

Where that automatically loads in any dependencies and you now do `require 'api'` instead, presuming your `$LOAD_PATH` includes this particular `lib/` path.